# Updating Azure Container App for new image tags does not work

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I am observing strange behavior. When updating azure container app with an image based on the git sha tag of the changes, the image is not being used:

```
    az containerapp up \
    --name dengine \
    --resource-group regn \
    --location eastus \
    --environment 'dengine' \
    --registry-username $$SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID \
    --registry-password $$SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD \
    --image dengine.azurecr.io/dengine:someshacodeherewouldnotwork \
    --target-port 8000 \
    --ingress external \
    --query properties.configuration.ingress.fqdn
```

However, when i use the `:latest` tag, it uses the image with the latest code changes. I do make sure that the images (both latest and the sha tagged) are in the azure container registry.

```
    az containerapp up \
    --name dengine \
    --resource-group regn \
    --location eastus \
    --environment 'dengine' \
    --registry-username $$SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID \
    --registry-password $$SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD \
    --image dengine.azurecr.io/dengine:latest \
    --target-port 8000 \
    --ingress external \
    --query properties.configuration.ingress.fqdn
```